# Which version is correct? (it or them)

Tags: grammar

Our clients are not only surprised by how much savings we find, but where we find it.

OR

Our clients are not only surprised by how much savings we find, but where we find them.

Comment: find savings, find them.

Answer (score 1):

Savings is plural in form. Use 'them'.

> savings ​ [ plural ] BANKING, FINANCE money that you keep, usually in
>   a bank account, instead of spending it

[Saving](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/saving)

Comment: If "savings" is a plural noun, why don't we say, "how **many** savings"?

Comment: Because it's also an uncountable noun. It just happens to be plural in form, and take plural verbs and determiners.

Comment: Ahhhhh I was looking for an example of a plural form uncountable, here it is!   They are very rare.  OED gives "oats" but I don't believe them - I certainly would think nothing at all of having "an oat" or "two oats".  It might be worth mentioning in the answer that this is an exception to the general rule of "uncountable nouns don't have plural forms".

Answer (score -2):

Looking at Merriam-Webster online dictionary, [savings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/savings) has a few different meanings. In definition #3a, it can mean "money put by", that is "saved up", like in a savings account or a piggy bank, for example. M-W labels this "saving" as a plural noun. But this is not the meaning in the example statement, "Our clients are not only surprised by how much savings we find, but where we find it/them."

Their clients would not be "surprised" at where their savings accounts or piggy banks were found.

The type of savings that is found in surprising places is the type defined by M-W definition #3c:

> "a usually specified lower cost —often used in plural // a *savings*
>   of 50 percent"

So this particular form of "savings" is "often used in plural", ... but often used in singular as well. Search on the phrase, "represents **a** savings of", and you will find many people using this word in the singular form.

So it is OK to say, "Our clients are not only surprised by how much savings we find, but where we find it." I think it sounds more idiomatic that way (but, FYI, I *do* use American style English). In fact, if you use "them", it almost sounds like "them" might even refer to the clients themselves.